# Vs code render the same tag often

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging, rendering, vscode-debugger

Good morning, everyone. I'm having an issue that I don't know what's happening. For some reason, my VS Code keeps re-rendering the changes I make to a project I create. In my case, I'm using Angular, and I've tested it on projects I created yesterday, and it's working fine. Today, I created a new project, and it opens the initial page normally. However, when I delete the HTML and add an h1 for testing purposes, it somehow starts re-rendering the tag multiple times until it breaks the site and stops loading altogether. Has anyone experienced this before? Do you know what might be happening?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gs4j.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oYty.png)

i tried create new projects, restart my computer, verify old projects (all works normally), i'm avoiding reinstall de vs code because i don't know if the problem is in it

Comment: The reason for your problem is that you are referencing the `<app-root>` component within the template for the `<app-root>` component!

Comment: mannnn i can't belive lol i'm sorry my bad, tks for the help, i need a coffe i think hahaha

Comment: ha ha, no worries.  Happens to the best of us :-)